# Naming ASN something else than "default", Cisco IOS XR

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, mpls-vpn, cisco-ios-xr

I'm trying to configure a BGP and VRF (for a L3VPN) on a Cisco ASR9000 router, as per [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr9000/software/asr9k-r6-3/lxvpn/configuration/guide/b-l3vpn-cg-asr9000-63x/b-l3vpn-cg-asr9000-63x_chapter_010.html#concept_DF9F4533EF4F455BBAB26DE67D7AC25F) tutorial.

I'm on the first section ("*Configuring Multiprotocol BGP on the PE Routers and Route Reflectors*").

I've followed the instructions and entered these commands:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03#config
Tue Sep 20 08:40:04.954 UTC
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config)#router bgp 1555
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config-bgp)#address-family vpnv4 unicast
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config-bgp-af)#neighbor 172.168.40.24 remote-as 2002
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config-bgp)#address-family vpnv4 unicast
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config-bgp-af)#commit
```

But got this error upon committing:

```
router bgp 1555
!!% The instance name is used already: asn 0.17676 inst-name default
 neighbor 172.168.40.24
  remote-as 2002
!!% The instance name is used already: asn 0.17676 inst-name default
 !
!
```

I'm assuming that somehow a `default` value is set on the ASN and that it clashes with the value set on `asn 0.17676`.

**Is that the case?**

And if so, how does one go about setting something else than the default `default` value?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that the `default` (global) BGP had the ID of 17676.

Therefore I just created a new address family underneath it:
(I also changed the remote-AS number and the neighbor IP)

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config)#router bgp 17676
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config-bgp)# address-family vpnv4 unicast
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config-bgp-af)#neighbor 172.168.55.55 remote-as 2184
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config-bgp)#address-family vpnv4 unicast
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config-bgp-af)#commit
```

I also suspect that the config got rejected because I tried to configure a BGP instance that didn't exist:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:fcs-662-vm-03(config)# router bgp 1555
```